# Error when trying to build with Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

My computer just crashed, blue screen of death.
When it rebooted I tried to start my android app on which i was working on, but as soon as Android Studio opens and Gradle starts compiling i get this error.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Error:java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I don't understand what is wrong, the code was working fine and nothing has changed. Please help !

Comment: Try to clean project and rebuild it

Comment: tried and i get the same thing

Comment: I can't actually clean the project, it bugs out when i clean it

Comment: Try File =>  Invalidate Caches / Restart = > Build => Make Project

Comment: same thing... still the same error

Comment: Delete `.android` directory from your Users (C:\Users\user_name\.android) home directory and start Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if the project was developed on different versions of Android Studio. You need to re-create the project on the latest Android Studio versions and then import the entire code in it. 
I have faced this issue many times during code porting from older Android Studio versions and also from Windows to Ubuntu based systems.

Comment: How do I import the code, I have never done that do i actually need to copy each file one by one ?

Comment: Get the package of code into your project directly and then copy android manifest and gradle file's contents accordingly